# List<MyObject> not being saved in EF Core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm using EF Core 2.2 with ASP.net MVC Core 2.2.

I have an entity with a List array that is not being stored to the table.
I thought that it would write out a list of foreign keys to the objects in the array, but that's not happening. What am I forgetting?

```
public class ProjectModel
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public List<MyObject> ListOfObjects { get; set; }

}

public class MyObject
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

Code where add and save is occurring:

```
MyObject cm = MethodToGenerateObject();

if(pm.ListOfObjects == null)
{
    pm.ListOfObjects = new List<MyObject>();
}

pm.ListOfObjects.Add(cm);

_context.Entry(pm).State = EntityState.Modified;

try
{
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
{
     throw;

}
```

But no MyObject data is saved to the database. Why?

Comment: How is MyObject in the DataBase? I don't really know what you are trying to do, but your code won't work like that

Comment: you should do something like this to save the list of MyObjects pm.ListOfObjects.ForEach(l => _context.Entry(l).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified);

Comment: Navigation properties should be virtual and of type ICollection<T> - I don't think ListOfObjects is being mapped properly as a nav property. You probably need a ProjectModel ID property on the other end side too to form the relationship ...

Comment: Instead of `pm.ListOfObjects.Add(cm);` you should do something like `_context.yourDatabaseTableNameInContext.AddRangeAsync(listOfObject)`

Comment: Found the answer, thanks @sam for the insight: https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/conventions/one-to-many-relationship

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Sam, I searched for navigation properties and found this helpful guide:
https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/conventions/one-to-many-relationship

the first one to many relationship example helped solve my problem.